# Application insights kusto query make list of all child items

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have results in application insights that I want to query. My data in application insights are requests, with child dependencies. They have the same operation_Id.
I would like to list all requests. I can easily do this by running the query: `request`
But I also want to have the same corresponding dependencies, in the same line. Just as a list. How can I do this with the `make_list()` operator?

Alternatively, I could accomplish this with a join. But I prefer to have the results in the same line, and the dependency names in a list as a column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this?

```
requests
| join (dependencies
    | summarize operationNameList=make_list(name),opid=count() by operation_Id
    | project operationNameList, operation_Id
    )
    on operation_Id
| project id, name, operationNameList
```

My idea is that, when use 'join', we can get several lines according to the dependency count. So using make_list to combine the dependency.

[image]